# Low frequency wave ability to penetrate object

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, signal-processing

as shown in this em wave spectrum image, the lower the frequency the better a wave ability to penetrate object.
https://c479107.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/files/20642/area14mp/pvgrynkw-1361853572.jpg

my question is why do we need to modulate voice to a higher frequency like in the case of operating a radio, if a lower frequency wave (human voice) can penetrate an object better.

to note: the spectrum image doesnt include a human voice as it is to low of a frequency. 
so my current speculation is that there is a cut off point somewhere, where it is too low for (the lower the frequency the better a wave ability to penetrate object) to hold true. 
if not the reason why we dont just send a voice without modulation is because energy is also an important factor in a wave ability to penetrate an object, and modulation help achieve greater energy.

Thank Bill, I forgot that mechanical wave and electromagnetic wave are to different things, and you should not really compare behavior of voice (mechanical wave) to a EM wave.

Comment: What do you mean by "modulate the voice to a higher frequency"?  They convert the voice into a higher frequency signal of a completely different propagation method, so I'm not really sure what this is trying to ask.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You cannot compare human voice or soundwaves to photons. Sound actually has a medium to form a wave and travel through. Millions of coherent photons may resemble a wave but there still individual photons traveling individual trajectories. Lower frequency photons actual penetrate walls but sound waves impact the wall and vibrate molecules all the way through to the other side. Two totally different things.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73971/discussion-on-answer-by-bill-alsept-low-frequency-wave-ability-to-penetrate-obje).

Answer (score 2):

(There seems to be some debate about the meaning of the question. I'm interpreting the question to mean: why don't we send voice communication over electromagnetic waves with the same frequencies as the sound waves that are being transmitted. E.g., if I make a 300 Hz sound, we would transmit it as a 300 Hz electromagnetic wave.)

We use higher frequencies mostly because low frequency antennas would be too large. A good antenna is going to be, roughly speaking, similar in size to the wavelength of the wave. So low frequency antennas are really big.

That said, very low frequency waves do have excellent penetration. For example, the US and Soviet navies used [extremely low frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency) (ELF) radio waves (3-30 Hz) to communicate with *submerged* submarines. The ELF radio waves have no issue penetrating the seawater and reaching the subs (but the data transfer rate was very slow). The antennas for these transmitters were very long. The US put its transmitters in national forests to make them less conspicuous (see linked article).